# Drag & Drop upload: Allow only one file

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs3

I wrote a little component, which allows me to upload multiple images by simply dragging and dropping:

```
<template>
    <div
        :class="{'border-dashed opacity-50': draggedOver}"
        @dragleave="dragleave" @dragover="dragover" @drop="drop">
        <input
            :name="`fields[assetsFieldHandle][]`"
            accept=".svg,.jpg,.jpeg,.png"
            class="w-px h-px opacity-0 overflow-hidden absolute"
            type="file"
            :multiple="canHandleMultipleFiles"
            @change="onChange($event)"/>
        <label :for="`fields[assetsFieldHandle]`"
               class="block cursor-pointer">
            // ...
        </label>
    </div>
</template>
<script setup>

function dragover(event) {
    console.log(event.dataTransfer.files)
    event.preventDefault();
    draggedOver.value = true;
}

function dragleave(event) {
    draggedOver.value = false;
}

function drop(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    fileinput.value.files = event.dataTransfer.files;
    filelist.value = [...event.dataTransfer.files];
    draggedOver.value = false;
    upload();
}
</script>
```

Now I want to dynamically allow the upload of either multiple files or only one. This works fine for the system's file picker dialog (in this dialog I can only choose one file, if `canHandleMultipleFiles` is not `true`.

But if I drag and drop multiple files into the drop zone, the upload is being triggered.

The `event` in `dragover(event)` does not contain any values in `event.dataTransfer.files`, so my attempt to disable the form if somebody drags more than one file, did not work out. In this case I'd manually set `cursor-not-allowed`.

Any idea on how to get this working?

Comment: Add a validation message, if user uploads invalid amount of files

Comment: That would be a possible solution, but not the best in my opinion - having a "disabled"-look on `dragover` would directly indicate that this action is not allowed.